# how to target event for "shift keydown & click" on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I want to control events when hovering a `<div>` element.

I have my code pretty much working, but I have 2 remaining problems!

1. When I first run the code in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9ea8/1/), I need to click on the body of the document first to get the keydown to be recognised. If I run the code and hover right away and press shift nothing happens. I have it running on doc ready,so not sure why I need to click first? Anyway to get this to work right way without needing to click?
2. I trace out in the console the `console.log('click and press');` This is getting fired each time I press `shift` and is not looking for a `click` - why is this getting fired when pressing shift when I call it within a function that says  `$(document).on('keydown click', function (e) {`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g9ea8/1/)**

My JS code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".target").hover(function () {

    $(document).on('keydown click', function (e) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            // code to go here for click
            console.log('click and press');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            // change cursor to ne-resize
            $('.target').css('cursor', 'ne-resize', 'important');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        // change cursor to sw-resize
        $('.target').css('cursor', 'sw-resize', 'important');
    });


});

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event binding is incorrect. you can use:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/g9ea8/8/

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hovering = false;

    $(".target").hover(function () {
        hovering = true;
    }, function() {
        hovering = false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        if (hovering && e.shiftKey) {
            // code to go here for click
            console.log('hovering+shift+click');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (hovering && e.shiftKey) {
            // change cursor to ne-resize
            $('.target').css('cursor', 'ne-resize', 'important');
            console.log('hovering+shift');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        // change cursor to sw-resize
        if(hovering) {
            $('.target').css('cursor', 'sw-resize', 'important');
            console.log('hovering+keyup');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This one still does not work without initially clicking the body

Comment: @Xavjer it's because when the fiddle is loaded, the frame does not have focus

Comment: That's correct, this was his first question now you answered them both ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason why you need to click first on the fiddle demo is because the frame doesn't have focus, normally this should work fine.
2. You shouldn't be attaching a `keydown` listener, you only need a to attach `click`, otherwise `keydown` will fire the event regardless of a `click` occurring.

Also, currently you're attaching 3 handlers every time you hover over `.target`, see @techfoobar's answer for a cleaner solution.